# Using a geojson file to programatically add popup polyline image on click

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet to plot a series of polylines. For each polyline, I have want a custom pop up which presents an image. I have managed to achieve this functionality for a single polyline and now wish to generate this functionality for a series of polylines, read from a `json` file.

```
    var map = L.map('map', {scrollWheelZoom:false}).setView([25.198696, 55.269794], 15);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

    var random_icon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/defaulticon/icons/png/256x256/media-shuffle.png',
        iconSize: [38, 95], // size of the icon
        popupAnchor: [0,-15]
        });
    var customPopup = "test image<br/><img src='http://i.imgur.com/NpZuKvK.png' alt='maptime logo gif' width='350px'/>";

    var customOptions =
        {
        'maxWidth': '500',
        'className' : 'custom'
        }

    var pointA = new L.LatLng(25.146619, 55.225746);
    var pointB = new L.LatLng(25.198696, 55.269794);
    var pointList = [pointA,pointB];

    L.polyline(pointList,{icon: random_icon,color:'red','weight':10}).bindPopup(customPopup,customOptions).addTo(map);
```

This presents a polyline which when clicked on, presents the image from `imgur`.

[image: Polyline pop up]

I have now created a geojson file which I've added [here](https://gist.github.com/gac55/52ab01944be1e39e154cd2a5709de737).

How do I got about a.loading this `geojson` file b. iterating through it and creating the following `var`'s : `customPopup` with the `url` from the `geojson`, the `pointList` and `points` from the `geojson` file and finally render the `polyline`?

Comment: See [Leaflet GeoJSON tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) and [leaflet-ajax plugin](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ghybs, the answer is in the documentation of Leaflet.

First, you need to get the GeoJson content by an Ajax request or whatever you want. Then, simply use L.geoJson options. Here is more or less what you need (it uses JQuery) :

```
function genPopup(url, name){
    return name + '<br/><img src="' + url + '" alt="maptime logo gif" width="350px"/>';
}

$.get('https://gist.github.com/gac55/52ab01944be1e39e154cd2a5709de737', function (data){
    var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data);

    L.geoJson(jsondata, {
        color: 'red',
        weight: 10,
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
            var furl = feature.properties.url;
            var fname = feature.properties.name;
            layer.bindPopup(
                genPopup(furl, fname),
                customOptions
            );
        }
    }).addTo(map);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Julien. Newb question, but what is the `$` before the `.get`?